# How to decode from web based output

Tags: python, xml, soap, base64, decoding

I want to decode decode my output using base64.b64decode because my ouput result is an instance or came from XML or SOAP not sure,

My "result" is something like this:

```
 Table = 
    (Table){
      ResultA = "77414454-GH"
      ResultB = "AB-21"
      ResultC = "1.1"
      }
```

My script is here:

```
print base64.b64decode(getattr(results['QueryResult']['NewDataSet']['Table'], "ResultB"))
```

but im always getting this error:

```
    print base64.b64decode(getattr(results['QueryResult']['NewDataSet']['Table'], "ResultB"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding
```

I already had this question but no one responding me, here my previous question for more details

[getting specific value in <type instance>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311640/getting-specific-value-in-type-instance)

Any Suggestion/Comments Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I have this error I try to fix it by hading "==" at the end of my string. But it could also be that it's not base64 that your trying to decode.

Comment: where do I need to put that "==" , I am not executing a conditional statement.

Comment: Like this string "VGhpcyBpcyBCYXNlNjQ". If you try to decode it you will have en Incorrect padding error, but if you had == at the end of this string (so it become "VGhpcyBpcyBCYXNlNjQ=="), it may pad the string correctly. But consider that your string may not be in base 64.